# iframe crashes Phonegap/Cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, iframe

Recently I noticed some weird issue about using iframe in phonegap. If I create blank phonegap 2.6.0 build and insert into body of index.html the following code

```
<iframe src="http://google.com/" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" onload="alert('loaded')"></iframe>
```

After deployment to the device (tested on Android 4.0.3 SGS2) the app behaves somehow inconsistently. For example if I run the app after device reboot onload event isn't triggered and after approximately 15 seconds the app shuts down without any error messages. If  I launch the app after that, alert appear and everything's fine

Though there are number of issues about iframe in phonegap I didn't manage to find one similar to this. Maybe anyone has an idea why that could happen and how to fix it

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `super.clearCache();` solves the problem.